# Java sequencer loops with a delay if connected to external Midi out device

Tags: java, midi, javasound

I want to loop a Midi sequence using the Java sequencer and its setLoopCount() method.

If sequencer's output is connected to an external Midi out device, there is a noticeable lag introduced each time sequence loops over.

If sequencer's is connected to the internal Java synth (Gervill) I don't notice any delay between loops. I tried with different loop points, it does not change the problem. I'm using Win10/Java 8.

```
  sequencer = MidiSystem.getSequencer(false);
  sequencer.open();
  Sequence sequence = MidiSystem.getSequence(midiFile);
  sequencer.setSequence(sequence);

  // outDevice=Java synth (Gervill)
  // or
  // outDevice=Edirol UA-25 (USB)
  Receiver outDeviceReceiver = outDevice.getReceiver();
  Transmitter seqTransmitter = sequencer.getTransmitter();
  seqTransmitter.setReceiver(outDeviceReceiver);

  int startLoopTick = 0;
  int endLoopTick = -1;  // Loop at end of sequence
  sequencer.setLoopStartPoint(startLoopTick);
  sequencer.setLoopEndPoint(endLoopTick);
  sequencer.setLoopCount(Sequencer.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY);

  // if outDevice==Edirol there is a slight delay between loops
  sequencer.start();
```

Comment: This sounds like a bug in your particular Java implementation.

Comment: I use Oracle JDK 8 for Win10 x64. Is there alternatives ?

Answer (score 0):

Sequencer automatic send controller msg after loop.
(reset all controller etc. 121,123,64 on all channels)
That is why it sound's delayed.

Comment: I think it would help if you added some code to help explain things. It's hard to understand what you're saying with the current form of the answer.